# producing the opposite of a regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to build a normaliser that detects all special characters and adds a space around them.

The problem is that there are different shapes of data and I need to keep them as they are, like: mails, dates, hours, decimal numbers (42.11) and links.

I built the ones that are for decimal numbers, hashtags, hours and mails (I'm not sure for the mail) where in each one: for example, in the hashtags, the tokeniser detects all the `#` in the text except the one that in a hashtag form `#test`.

In every case, I tried to built a regex that targets the opposite of each situation.

Below, a code sample with the regex:

```
def clean_str(string):
    string = re.sub(r"((?<=\D)\.(?=\D)?|(?<=\D)?\.(?=\D))", " . ", string) #. numbers 44.55
    string = re.sub(r"((?<=\D)\:(?=\D)?|(?<=\D)?\:(?=\D))", " . ", string) #. Hours
    string = re.sub(r"((?<!\s)(@|#)|(@|#)(?=[^a-zA-Z]))", " . ", string) #. Hashtags
    string = re.sub(r"((?<=[^a-zA-Z])?@(?=[^a-zA-Z])[^.]?|(?<=[^a-zA-Z])@(?=[^a-zA-Z])?[^.])", " . ", string) #. mails
    string = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]", " , ", string) #, all speciall characters    
    return string.strip().lower()
```

The problem is, if I want to build the one that is for the mails, there are multiple opposite cases for this `test@test.com` to take into account.

For example:

```
test@.com
@.
@test.com
.
.
```

Where in the regex scripts for decimal numbers, it is much easier since there are only two sides to check `LEFTSIDE.RIGHTSIDE`.

So what is the right way to build such a regex script for links, mails and so on?

Did I miss something?

----- Edited

To make my question more clear, if I have this input text:

```
"I will to! then we# are test@test.com but .not so."
```

The output should be like this:

```
I 
want 
to
! 
then 
we
# 
are 
test@test.com 
but 
.
not 
so
.
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Can you post some specific example input and output? Also, if you want to match the "opposite" of some regex R, you might try to _split_ by R instead and keep the rest. Similarly, instead of removing everything that's the "opposite" of R (as you seem to do) why not just find matches for R itself?

Comment: If I'm understanding, you're trying to write a regular expression that matches everything except email addresses? Or could you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: Please provide a list of input and desired output that covers all of your expected cases.

Comment: The question was edited ..

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're wanting to build is a parser, which likely can't be done via RegEx (it *may be* possible, though it'd be more efficient via a parser). In this case, you'd run a lexical analyzer to scan the source code and convert your lexemes into tokens. this can be as simple as a few categories:

- Digits
- Decimal Place
- Hashsign
- Colon
- "At" sign
- Generic Catch All

Then you'd iterate through each token to check if it can be parsed into the desired format through syntax analysis. Because your desired syntax is so simple, a recursive descent parser could be used. I don't know what you want to do with the data (aside from validating it), but typically during the syntax analysis phase you'd build a parse or syntax tree. I haven't used Python in many years, but some pseudo code for your syntax analysis phase would be:

```
function parseNumber(source, index) {
    if source.subString(index).startsWith(digits) {
        index += number.Length
        if source.subString(index).startsWith(decimal_place) {
            index += decimal_place.Length
            if source.subString(index).startsWith(digits) {
                index += number.Length
            } else {
                index -= decimal_place.Length
            }
        }
        return True
    }
    return False
}
```

Comment: thanx, I liked the idea .. but let me wait , maybe there are other ways ..